# Is there a way to select items from a specific to the last one in the container using only CSS?

Tags: css

I have couple dozens of items in a container. I want to select last half of them and modify their style.

Comment: Your question is not full. Please provide some sample code, snippet or something. Second please read this before post a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the last half of them in a div and give it a class. Then use the class to select them and apply styles.